# How do I know my position inside an li when interacting with an element inside that li?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am dynamically appending to the main to-do "list" `ul`.

```
<li>
 <div class="description">
   <input class="descriptionInput" type="text">
 </div>
</li>
```

[image]

How do I know I'm inside the 2nd `li` when performing an event on the description `input`? (trying to retrieve the text of the `li` the input is inside of)

I can't for the life of me figure out how to sort of select "backwards".

Would appreciate a few hints or terms to google.

Thanks!

Comment: Please show your JavaScript, with your eventhandlers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Finding the LI element

- the `this` value inside an event handler is the object on which the handler has been attached, whether by `addEventListener` or by assigning a function to an "onEventName" property/attribute. But if event handling is delegated, `this` may not be the object on which the event was fired.
- the `target` property of the`event` object is the object on which the event was fired. (`srcElement` is a proprietary and non standard [alias](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/srcElement%7D) of `target`.)

So if you are listening for an event fired on the input, e.g. "change", the `li` element is in the parent node chain, which you could code directly in a handler as

```
function (event) {
    let li = event.target.parentNode.parentNode;
    //... do stuff with li
```

which is brittle by assuming a particular element structure, or by searching the parent node chain:

```
function (event) {
    let li;
    for( li = event.target; li = li.parentNode;) {
        if( li.tagName == "LI") {
            break;
        }
    }
    // process li ....
```

which finds the LI element or leaves `li` set to `null`.

#### Finding its position in the List

If the unordered or ordered element does not have its own id, you can find it in the parent node chain of the input element in similar fashion to finding the LI element above (i.e. by coding directly or searching).

The position of the LI element in the OL or UL list entries can be found by searching and matching it with an element in the [`children`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ParentNode/children) property  of the OL/UL element.

*Note that  the `node.children` collection is live and should not be used while sorting LI elements by dynamically moving their positions around in the DOM.*

Answer (score 0):

You can use `index()` function for this.
If you are working with the input field under the list item. Then just select like this:

```
$("input.descriptionInput").parents("li").index();
```

I think it will work for you.

Comment: thanks, a mix of your and traktor53's answer solved the issue!

Answer (score 0):

Your event should have a srcElement property, which contains the element from which the element originated. From there you can traverse through the DOM to get to the grand-parent element.

for example:

```
myElement.addEventListener('keyup',function(event){
  let input=event.srcElement;
  let div=input.parentElement;
  let li=div.parentElement;
  console.log(li.textContent);
  //or just (event.srcElement.parentElement.parentElement.textContent)
})
```

Of course this only works if you're sure that the input will always be the grand-child of the li. If another element gets added for whatever reason, your code will break. It's safer to search for the element

I would just search for the element using a while loop.

```
let element=event.srcElement;
//while the element isn't an li, and it has a parentElement;
while(element.tagName !=='LI' && element.parentElement){
  element=element.parentElement;
}
console.log(element) //should have found the first li ancestor
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `.closest` function to navigate to the nearest `li` and then use `index()` to determine the index. Also, since you are dynamically adding li, you might need to add `change` listener to the DOM.

```
  <ul>
   <li>
    <div class="description">
       <input class="descriptionInput" type="text">
    </div>
   </li>
    <li>
    <div class="description">
       <input class="descriptionInput" type="text">
   </div>
   </li>
 </ul>

<script>
    $(document).on('change','ul li input.descriptionInput', function(){
         var index = $(this).closest('li').index();
          alert(index);
    });
</script>
```

Example : https://jsfiddle.net/xpvt214o/874826/